# Insert row in table for each id from another table

Tags: mysql, database, subquery, sql-insert

Basically I have two tables like these:

**Table 1: users**

```
id_user, name, ...
```

**Table 2: leaves**

```
id_2, employee (the column employee is the id of the user from the first table), ...
```

Right now the table two is empty (doesn't have rows) and for every user from the first table I want to create a row on the second one inserting the id from the first table as a value in the column employee, like:

**Table 2: leaves**

```
id    employee    column1    column2    column3    column4    column5   
id1   1           date1      date2      integer1   integer2   string
id2   2           date1      date2      integer1   integer2   string
...
```

The INSERTS I tried:

1. This one works fine:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO entitleddays (employee, startdate, enddate, type, days, description)
   VALUES (1, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', 3, 5, 'test');
   ```
2. Here I tried what I explained above, but it doesn't work:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO entitleddays (employee, startdate, enddate, type, days, description)
   VALUES ((SELECT id from users), '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', 3, 5, 'test');
   ```

I get the following error:

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I do understand the error: the subquery is finding more than one result so it cannot insert the value into employee, my problem is that I don't know what syntax should I use as the noob I am. I just want to create a row in the second table for every row from the first table (using the id from the first table).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO entitleddays (employee, startdate, enddate, type, days, description)
    SELECT id, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', 3, 5, 'test'
    FROM users;
```

Comment: Noob, FYI, the sub-query `(SELECT id from users)` is what is returning multiple rows, while the `VALUE()` segment should only be one row. So the statement you've created has multiple values for the first column of `VALUES()`, which isn't valid sql.

Comment: As simple as that... Thanks!